# MySQL Workbench Syntax

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a simplle ddl trigger in MySQL Workbench 6.3 for the CREATE TABLE statement. I am getting a syntax error on line 2.  Is this the correct syntax for MySQL?  If it is, any idea what I'm doing wrong.  This is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DDL_TableAdd
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_TABLE
AS
BEGIN 
    'You do not have permission to add tables to this database.'
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create triggers only on tables, not on an entire database. Besides, if the user doesn't have the requisite permissions, the query will fail before ever triggering your trigger, anyway.

In any event, your `ON DATABASE` is invalid syntax. See [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html).

Comment: Thank you.  This is for a project I am working on for grad school.  The syntax I used is exactly what is written in the book.  I may have to re-write it for each table.

Answer (score 0):

To control permissions on the database and tables, you can use the GRANT syntax.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html#grant-privileges

You do not need to create such triggers as it usually falls into the role of access permissions, regardless of which database you are using (eg. mysql, oracle, db2 etc.)